# Plotly legend overlap x label and decrease graph size

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I've got difficulties to correctly set up the legend of a plotly graph. The graph i'm trying to set up is part of a process that generates this graph automatically and may have more or less plots. In my case, this is fine if I don't have a lot of plots. Legend is below the graph, centered. Now, if I have a lot of plots, first, the legend overlap the x-label, and secondly, it shrinks the graph. I noted that the legend increases in size until a certain value and then a scrollbar appears. Is there any way to define the moment this scrollbar appears? Like "no more than 4 rows"? I think this would solve both issues at the same time.
Here below is the graph with a reasonable amout of plots (it is fine):
[image: Graph that is fine]

And this is the graph with a lot of plots that is not fine:
[image: Not ok graph]

Here below is my code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from plotly.io import to_html

axisParameters = {"visible": True,
                  "showspikes": True,
                  "gridcolor": "#C7C7C7",
                  "showline": True,
                  "linecolor": "Black",
                  "mirror": True,
                  "tickfont": {"family": "Arial", "size": 20},
                  "ticks": 'outside',
                  "tickmode": "auto",
                  "nticks": 20,
                  "automargin": True,
                  "zeroline": True,
                  "zerolinecolor": "#C7C7C7",
                  "showdividers": True,
                  "dividerwidth": 5,
                  "dividercolor": "red"}

my_graph = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

my_graph.update_layout(title=dict(text="TITLE", x=0.5, font={"family": "Arial", "size": 30}), showlegend=False)

my_graph.update_layout(yaxis={"title": {"text": "Y_LABEL",
                                                #"standoff": 25,
                                                "font": {"family": "Arial", "size": 24}},
                                      "showexponent": "all",
                                      "exponentformat": 'E',
                              "tickfont": {"family": "Arial", "size": 20},
                                **axisParameters})

my_graph.update_layout(xaxis={"title": {"text": "X_LABEL",
                                                #"standoff": 25,
                                                "font": {"family": "Arial", "size": 24}
                                                },
                             **axisParameters})

my_graph.update_layout(margin={"l": 110, "r": 10, "t": 100, "b": 10, "autoexpand": True},
                       autosize=False,
                       plot_bgcolor='white',
                       uniformtext={"mode": "hide", "minsize": 15},
                       width=1700, 
                       height=1000
                       )

for i in range(150):
    newPlot = go.Scatter(x=[0,100,150],
                     y=[0,50,70],
                     name=f"very_long_name_{i}",
                     mode="lines",
                     yaxis='y1',
                     legendgroup=f"very_long_name_{i}",
                     showlegend=True
                     )

    my_graph.add_trace(newPlot)
    
my_graph.update_layout(showlegend=True,
                       legend={"bordercolor": 'Grey',
                               "borderwidth": 1.0,
                               "yanchor": "top",
                               "xanchor": "center",
                               "x": 0.49,
                               "y": -0.20,
                               "orientation": "h",
                               "itemwidth": 30,
                               "font": {"family": "Arial", "size": 20}
                               })


fileName = r"test.html"
""" Generate figure in html """
div = to_html(fig=my_graph,
              full_html=False,
              default_width='100%',
              default_height='100%',
              config={
                  'toImageButtonOptions': {
                      'format': 'png',  # one of png, svg, jpeg, webp
                      'filename': fileName,
                      #'height': 1680,
                      #'width': 1680,
                      'autosize': False,
                      'scale': 1  # Multiply title/legend/axis/canvas sizes by this factor
                  },
                  'displaylogo': False,
              }
              )

html_string = '''
            <html>
                <head>
                    <style>body{background:white;height:125vh;width: 90vw; }</style>
                </head>
                <body>
                     <div id=plot">''' + div + '''</div>
                </body>
            </html>'''

with open(fileName, 'w') as f:
    f.write(html_string)
```